# What are the effects of inner functions on instantiated objects?

Tags: scala, guava, typetoken

The code below fails when constructing

```
 new TypeParameter[K]() {}
```

Only the location of the mapToken differs.

```
package net.ailive;

import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter;
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

class SampleJUnitScala {

  // Succeeds if defined here ***
  // def mapToken[K, V](keyToken: TypeToken[K], valueToken: TypeToken[V]): TypeToken[Map[K, V]] = {
  //    return new TypeToken[Map[K, V]]() {}
  //      .where(new TypeParameter[K]() {}, keyToken)
  //      .where(new TypeParameter[V]() {}, valueToken);
  // }

  @Test
  def myTest() = {

    // Fails if defined here ***
    def mapToken[K, V](keyToken: TypeToken[K], valueToken: TypeToken[V]): TypeToken[Map[K, V]] = {
      return new TypeToken[Map[K, V]]() {}
        .where(new TypeParameter[K]() {}, keyToken)
        .where(new TypeParameter[V]() {}, valueToken);
    }

    val mapTok = mapToken(
      TypeToken.of(classOf[String]),
      TypeToken.of(classOf[BigInteger]));
    val complexToken = mapToken(
      TypeToken.of(classOf[Integer]),
      new TypeToken[Queue[String]]() {});
  }
}
```

(TypeParameter.capture() returns null).

If I change the location of mapToken function. It works. Why?

Seen in Scala: 2.10

---

TypeToken comes from: (?)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hmm, very strange. Provided that there is no outer variable automatically passed to mapToken, both of them should AFAIK compile to the same bytecode. Could you publish the least compilable snippet? I can diff the bytecode then.

Comment: @v6ak -- Have added full sample.

Comment: Have you tried it without the unnecessary return statement?

Comment: No... because it dies before then in the TypeParameter constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There are some rather minor differences in the bytecode. Added `private final` to mapToken, renamed mapToken to `mapToken$1` and changed order of the methods. Still one test passes and one does not. The only difference in the bytecode (except the class name) I can see is generic parameters: https://public.v6ak.com/scala-inner-vs-outer-function.png

When looking at the inner classes (e.g. `SampleJUnitScalaOuterFunction$$anon$1`), they look the same except the names.

The generic parameters are not used by JVM, they are used compile-time and also by Guava. The contructor of `TypeParameter<T>` tries to read its type parameter `T`.

I am, however, not sure, why `mapToken` works when used in the outer function. Type parameters aren't passed in runtime and Guava should not be able to read the actual type from `new TypeParameter[K]()`, because the `SampleJUnitScalaOuterFunction$$anon$3` class is generic.